# Can I write Information into the mini-buffer (like an extra mode line)

Tags: minibuffer, echo-area

I was wondering if it is possible (with any reasonable amount of work) to write infos into the mini buffer (because not every window needs to tell me the time for example).

Comment: I think the [echo area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html) which you actually mean by "minibuffer" is not intented for such information. Naturally you can output messages of any kind there. But, there goes normally instant user notification or information about the thing at point. It does usually not permanently display general information such as the time. I think a better way to reach what you want would be to surpress the time display in the status lines of all windows but one (e.g., the most bottom-left one).

Comment: @Stefan, if you could post the relevant part of your answer from http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/31978 that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and there's even a package for that which you can install from GNU ELPA: [minibuffer-line](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/minibuffer-line.html)